# Vuetify v-card fit like a puzzle (Masonry layout)

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a page with 6 or more v-card.

Is there a way to fit them like a puzzle? I would like to remove white space between small v-card on first and second line.

Now is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**No way** (Yet) to solve this by Vuetify API.
Related Github `Feature` Req:

[[Feature Request] Masonry Layout #4091](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4091)

### Solution by Masonry.js

Use Javascript plugin. For example [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

**Codepen Demo:** https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/gOpZqKr

### Masonry.js & vuetify grid - Code snippet

```html
<!-- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/ -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-container>
      <v-row class="masonry">
        <v-col class="child" cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-card class="pa-2" color="pink darken-1" dark>
            <v-card-title>Card 1</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections form, Rackham. One of three columns
              The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections form, Rackham.
              </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <!-- card 2-->
        <v-col class="child" cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-card class="pa-2"  color="orange darken-3" dark>
            <v-card-title>Card 2</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              One The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is 
              </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <!-- card 3 -->
        <v-col class="child" cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-card class="pa-2" color="#385F73" dark >
            <v-card-title>Card 3</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              The chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections form, Rackham.
              </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <!-- card 4 -->
        <v-col class="child" cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-card class="pa-2" color="blue darken-4" dark >
            <v-card-title>Card 4</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections form, Rackham.
              </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  mounted: function () {
      // Code that will run only after the
      // entire view has been rendered
      var msnry = new Masonry( '.masonry', {
        // options
        itemSelector: "[class*='col-']",
      });
  }
})
</script>
```

#### How to (Less than 1 min)

**Step 1/3: CDN before body**

Link directly to Masonry files on [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/).

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>`

**-or-** Install with **npm**: `npm install masonry-layout`
and use **import** `import Masonry from 'masonry-layout'`

**Step 2/3: HTML - Set container element**

> Masonry works on a container grid element with a group of child items.

Add a `class` (or `id`) to your flexbox grid (Set as `container element`).
`masonry` in this example (Use any name you want).

```
<v-row class="masonry">
  <v-col class="child" cols="12" sm="6">
   <v-card class="pa-2" outlined >
..rest of the code
```

**Step 3/3: Initialize with vanilla js**

`new Masonry( elem, options )`

**3.1:** Use `.masonry` as a container element argument.

**3.2:** Inside options object - set `itemSelector` to:
`itemSelector: "[class*='col-']"`

`[class*='col-']`: [Wildcard selector](http://www.brendanconnolly.net/css-wildcard-selectors/) (Select any class Contains `col`. For example: `.col-6` -or- `.col-md-2` ==> DRY // Clean solution)

I load the script inside vue mounted() [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) (After the components added to the DOM).

```
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  mounted: function () {
      // Code that will run only after the
      // entire view has been rendered
      var msnry = new Masonry( '.masonry', {
        // options
        itemSelector: "[class*='col-']",
      });
  }
})
```

#### Docs:

- **masonry.js docs:**
  https://masonry.desandro.com/
- **Vuetify grid systems docs:** https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/

---

### Solution by custom CSS

One more option is to use flexbox/Grid and Custom CSS, in my opinion, this is too much code & ideas for such a simple task. Related article:

https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/

Comment: For step 3 better use:

mounted () {
    new Masonry(document.querySelector('.masonry'), {
      // options
      itemSelector: ".child",
    })
  }

Comment: Thank you for documenting the use with Vuetify! It workt on the first attempt <3

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **VueJs** and **Vuetify** then try to use [vue.js masonry](https://github.com/shershen08/vue-masonry). With vue-masony, all you need to do is `v-row` and `v-col` instead of `div`.

```html
<v-row v-masonry transition-duration="0.3s" item-selector=".item">
    <v-col v-masonry-tile class="item" cols="12" v-for="(content_obj, index) in class_contents" key="`content${index}`" sm="3" >
            ...
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution ([in this blog](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/)) with anything else than CSS. The same blog gives more examples of different grids and also some examples to make things prettier with JS.

The easiest way is to define a grid of columns the way you want. For example, I want on my proyect a 3 column grid about `400px` each.

So we define a class `masonry-with-columns`, we put all the properties we want (margin, padding, column-gap, row-gap, etc)

```css
.masonry-with-columns {
    columns: 3 400px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Each child must have 2 properties

```css
.masonry-with-columns div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

- `inline-block`: prevents objects from being cut
- `width: 100%`: When you do not put this property, at the time of loading it is displayed with a reduced width and then it expands, to avoid that, we must define a width

## Example

```
<template>
    <v-container
        fill-height
        fluid
    >
        <div class="masonry-with-columns">
            <NoticeCard
                v-for="(notice, idx) in notices"
                :key="idx"
                v-bind.sync="notice"
            ></NoticeCard>
        </div>
    </v-container>
</template>
import NoticeCard from '@/components/common/Notices/NoticeCard';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            notices: []
        }
    },
    components:{
        NoticeCard
    },
    methods: {
        getNotices() {
            axiosRequest.get('/get-cards').then((response) => {
                if ( response.status === 200 )
                    this.notices = response.data[0];
            }).catch(e => axiosResponseErrorHandler(this, e));
        },
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
    .masonry-with-columns {
        columns: 3 400px;
        column-gap: 10px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .masonry-with-columns div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

**Comments**

- Notices are filled with a server response
- NoticeCard is your card

## Results

[image]

[image]